# SSRS SUM() a grouped value outside of group

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, aggregate

I have a dynamically driven grouping, in this case group of values based on 3 items of their net and qty given a dynamic date range, grouped by month. I would like to get the total Net & QTY for each row, as I already have a group total by column.

So under [Total Quantity], I would like to get the sum of the result under Net which is already a value of [Sum(Net)]. I have used the following code: `=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox15.Value)` to only get the error:

> The Value expression for the textrun
> 'Textbox8.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a
> report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items
> contained in page headers and footers.

What would be a better way to get these results?

[image]

[image]

Comment: update your question add  your sql code  .. the related tables schema, a proper data sample and the expcted result  (as tabular text  ... not img only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your expression to

```
=SUM(Fields!Net.Value)
```

The expression will be exactly the same as the `Net` column that is inside your Product column group.

SSRS evaluates expressions based on the scope of the containing object, so in your case the scope of Textbox15 is inside both a row and column group, so the `SUM` only sums values inside those groups. By adding a column outside your Product column group, that textbox's scope is only within the row group, so the `SUM` adds up everything within that row group only and ignores column groups.

You can achieve the same thing by right-clicking your column group name (below the main report design) and selecting "Add Total / After"